# use variable in select query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to store column value for previous row in variable and then compare this variable value with column for current row. In mysql, example in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27d73/3)

so lets take simple example same as loaded in sql fiddle

```
create table align1 (col1 varchar(100),col2 varchar(100));

insert into align1 values ('1','1');
insert into align1 values ('1','1');
insert into align1 values ('10','1');
insert into align1 values ('100','1');
```

What I want to achieve is if value for col1 is same for previous row and current row then increment

query:

```
select col1,col2,if(@temp1=col1,@i:=@i+1, @i:=1) as  _keycol,@temp1:=col1 from align1,(select @temp1:=null,@i:=0)t
```

everything is perfect in mysql.

Now I want to achieve same query in sql server.

in mysql I have used session variable so I did not need to declare but in sql server I need to declare first.

I tried below query in sql server 2012, [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27d73/11)

```
declare @temp1 varchar(1024)='',@i int =0 
select col1,col2,case when @temp1=col1 then  @i=@i+1 else @i=1 end as  _keycol,@temp1=col1 from align1;
```

I am not able to execute above query and It give me error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

Then I just tried to increment number to make sure that can I able to increment variable value in  select query.. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9dd16/1):

```
declare @i int =0 
select col1,@i=@i+1  from align1
```

I got the error:

```
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations
```

Even I use LAG() then how can I increment or reset variable conditionally in select statement.

So I want to get same result in sql server 2012 same in mysql.

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me in an SSMS query window in SQL Server 2012. (this is my first time posting here so please forgive me if it's not formatted correctly!)

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP TABLE #temp

create table align1 (col1 varchar(100),col2 varchar(100));

insert into align1 values ('1','1');
insert into align1 values ('1','1');
insert into align1 values ('10','1');
insert into align1 values ('100','1');
insert into align1 values ('100','1');
insert into align1 values ('300','1');
insert into align1 values ('500','1');
insert into align1 values ('500','1');

DECLARE @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @prev  VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @current VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @i INT = 0;

SELECT @count = count(*) from align1

SELECT * INTO #temp FROM align1
SET @current = (SELECT TOP 1 col1 FROM #temp)
DELETE TOP (1) FROM #temp

WHILE @Count > 0
BEGIN
SET @prev = @current;
SET @current = (SELECT TOP 1 col1 From #temp)
IF @current = @prev 
   BEGIN
   SET @i = @i + 1;
   END
 DELETE TOP (1) FROM #temp;
 SET @Count = @Count - 1;
END

PRINT '@i = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i)
```

Result:

```
    @i = 3
```